# Gridview does not refresh display updated record

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am currently working on a project. I suddenly stumbled on a problem that really blew my brains. I have a function that displays the content of a table in a database to a gridview which I named bindGrid. It is working perfectly fine when I query 50 to 90 records. However when I query 100 records or more the gridview does not display the records until I change the value of my dropdown box that is set to autopostback.

Here is the sample of the code:

```
Protected Sub btnFilter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFilter.Click
        If cboFilter.Text = "DMZ" Then
            lblErrFilter.Visible = False
            lblError.Visible = False
            If drpYear.Text = "--Select--" Or drpMonth.Text = "--Select--" Or txtDMZ.Text = "--Select--" Or txtTop.Text = "" Then
                If drpYear.Text = "--Select--" Then
                    lblErrYear.Visible = True
                Else
                    lblErrYear.Visible = False
                End If
                If drpMonth.Text = "--Select--" Then
                    lblErrMonth.Visible = True
                Else
                    lblErrMonth.Visible = False
                End If
                If txtDMZ.Text = "--Select--" Then
                    lblErrDMZ.Visible = True
                Else
                    lblErrDMZ.Visible = False
                End If
                lblError.Visible = True
                lblError.Text = "No value specified for the following parameter(s) *."
            Else
                lblErrYear.Visible = False
                lblErrMonth.Visible = False
                lblErrDMZ.Visible = False
                Call bindData()
                'If Me.IsPostBack = True Then
                Call bindGrid()
                'End If
                '
            End If
        '__________________________________________________________________________
        'Zone filter
    ElseIf cboFilter.Text = "Zone and Book" Then
        lblErrFilter.Visible = False
        lblError.Visible = False
        If drpYear.Text = "--Select--" Or drpMonth.Text = "--Select--" Or txtZone.Text = "--Select--" Or txtTop.Text = "" Then
            If drpYear.Text = "--Select--" Then
                lblErrYear.Visible = True
            Else
                lblErrYear.Visible = False
            End If
            If drpMonth.Text = "--Select--" Then
                lblErrMonth.Visible = True
            Else
                lblErrMonth.Visible = False
            End If
            If txtZone.Text = "--Select--" Then
                lblErrZone.Visible = True
            Else
                lblErrZone.Visible = False
            End If
            lblError.Visible = True
            lblError.Text = "No value specified for the following parameter(s) *."
        Else
            lblErrYear.Visible = False
            lblErrMonth.Visible = False
            lblErrZone.Visible = False
            Call bindData()
            Call bindGrid()
        End If
    ElseIf cboFilter.Text = "Account Number" Then
        If txtFrom.Visible = True And txtTo.Visible = True Then
            If drpYear.Text = "--Select--" Or drpMonth.Text = "--Select--" Or txtFrom.Text = "" Or txtTo.Text = "" Then
                If drpYear.Text = "--Select--" Then
                    lblErrYear.Visible = True
                Else
                    lblErrYear.Visible = False
                End If
                If drpMonth.Text = "--Select--" Then
                    lblErrMonth.Visible = True
                Else
                    lblErrMonth.Visible = False
                End If
                If txtFrom.Text = "" Then
                    lblErrR1.Visible = True
                Else
                    lblErrR1.Visible = False
                End If
                If txtTo.Text = "" Then
                    lblErrR2.Visible = True
                Else
                    lblErrR2.Visible = False
                End If
                lblError.Visible = True
                lblError.Text = "No value specified for the following parameter(s) *."
            Else
                Call bindData()
                Call bindGrid()
            End If
        Else
            If drpYear.Text = "--Select--" Or drpMonth.Text = "--Select--" Or lstAcct.Items.Count = 0 Then
                If drpYear.Text = "--Select--" Then
                    lblErrYear.Visible = True
                Else
                    lblErrYear.Visible = False
                End If
                If drpMonth.Text = "--Select--" Then
                    lblErrMonth.Visible = True
                Else
                    lblErrMonth.Visible = False
                End If
                If lstAcct.Items.Count = 0 Then
                    lblErrAcct.Visible = True
                Else
                    lblErrAcct.Visible = False
                End If

                lblError.Visible = True
                lblError.Text = "No value specified for the following parameter(s) *."
            Else
                lblErrYear.Visible = False
                lblErrMonth.Visible = False
                lblErrR1.Visible = False
                lblErrR2.Visible = False
                Call bindData()
                Call bindGrid()
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If cboFilter.Text = "--Select--" Then
            lblErrFilter.Visible = True
        End If
        lblError.Visible = True
        lblError.Text = "No value specified for the following parameter(s) *."
    End If
    'Response.Redirect("~/Sites/CD/TopCon.aspx", True)
End Sub
```

as you can see the execution is done after I click on the filter button.

Here is my page load:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = False Then
        Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx", True)
    Else
        If User.IsInRole("chicken") = True Or User.IsInRole("dog") = True Or User.IsInRole("cat") = True Then
            If Not IsPostBack Then
                maxTop = 10
                txtTop.Text = maxTop
                Call bindData()
                Call bindGrid()
                lblUser.Text = lblUser.Text & User.Identity.Name
                lblIP.Text = lblIP.Text & GetIPAddress()
                cboFilter.TabIndex = 0
                Call fillYear()
                Call fillDMZCombo()
                Call fillZoneCombo()
                Call fillType()
            Else
                *Call bindGrid()*
            End If
        Else
            Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx", True)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Well I know the reason why the gridview refreshes when I click on my control that is set to autopostback it's because of the bindGrid that I inserted on my page_load inside the else.

It really seems to be a passive line of code. What really bothers me is why is it that my bindGrid inside the filter button does not execute when I query 100 records or more.

Here is my code for bindGrid:

```
Public Sub bindGrid()
    IpAdd = GetIPAddress()
    xUser = User.Identity.Name

    ShowCon = New SqlConnection("some data connection")
    ShowCon.Open()

    cmdShowCon = ShowCon.CreateCommand
    cmdShowCon.CommandTimeout = 600
    cmdShowCon.CommandText = "some simple select statement"
    daShowCon.SelectCommand = cmdShowCon
    dsShowCon.Clear()
    daShowCon.Fill(dsShowCon, "someTable")

    grdTopCon.DataSource = dsShowCon
    grdTopCon.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a breakpoint in the `btnFilter_Click` to see what's causing the problem. It maybe either caused by the algorithm inside it or inside the `Page_Load` event.